# How can I speed up the module registry approval proces on Drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

The module is done, the code and documentation meets the prescribed standards for Drupal projects, the sandbox project has been created and [submitted for review](http://drupal.org/node/1011698). What more can be done to help speed the review process for a contributors first module?

I don't actually have a module in this position, but recently met a developer who was trying to get a module approved that integrated his new CAPTCHA service into Drupal. Hopefully someone has reviewed and approved it, but you can take a look at the application [here](http://drupal.org/node/1237362) to see how the approval process can stagnate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process can be very slow unfortunately. There probably isn't a complete answer, but I can give a few hints.

Try to find users which test and report that it works (as detailed as possible), developers to review it and report that too. There are many ways to do that, for example for developers:

- Ask in IRC (#drupal-contribute) (Remember to offer something in return, e.g. patch reviews). Do not ask multiple times and only when the channel is quiet.
- Review/test applications of other users and ask for a review of yours in return.
- If your module interacts with other modules, ask their maintainers to review the integration code. Again, you could help with the issue queue of these modules (review, write patches, answer support questions)

This has two advantages. a) It shows that your module works and users are interested in using it. b) It helps to keep it on top of the (very long) list of issues.

Also, try to make it as easy as possible to install and test your module. For example, if your module integrates with a third-party service/website, provide a test account for it or make it possible to register there for free (if it isn't anyway) and provide detailed installation instructions (for example in a README.txt or INSTALL.txt file).

Answer (score 0):

Please don't go into #drupal-contribute and pester for reviews. It never works out well. There's a long line of people waiting, and a shorter line of people reviewing.

Thankfully though, there is a proposal to [revamp the project application process](http://groups.drupal.org/node/180444). Hopefully that will be resolved soon.

Comment: Updated my answer, I think it's ok to ask once when the channel is quiet.